# Shell script to duplicate directory, lock one, and move both to new directory - almost there?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I'm a reporter who works with data sets. Every time I receive a new data set, I do two things immediately: Duplicate the file(s) and lock the originals.

I want to automate that process. By altering [a shell script I use to create nested folders for reporting projects](http://www.jsguntzel.com/skinnynotebook/2011/06/30/my-fellow-reporters-keep-your-story-files-organized-with-this-handy-shell-script/) and stringing it together with a bunch of commands, I was able to achieve the basic functionality, but it is messy. I would be grateful for your help in streamlining.

Here's what I'm doing now (bear with me and I promise to be as clear as possible):

I download the data to a Desktop folder called "DataInbox" where I also have the following shell script, saved as newdata.sh:

```
    #!/bin/bash

if [[ -z "${1}" ]]; then
  die "FolderName Required"
fi


/bin/mkdir -p ~/Desktop/DataFarm/$1/{ProtectedOrig,Data}

echo -n "---Data Folder Setup

---Data Introduction

---Data Audit/Manipulation

---Data Queries" > ~/Desktop/DataFarm/$1/Data/DataJournal.txt
```

By executing `bash newdata.sh DirectoryName` I create a directory with the subfolders "Data" and "ProtectedOrig" and a text file called "DataJournal.txt" with four headings built in.

Inside the "DataInbox" directory I run this mess, only strung together with `&&`:

```
$ ditto NewData/  NewDataCopy

$ bash newdata.sh DirectoryName

$ mv NewData/ /Users/JSG/Desktop/DataFarm/DirectoryName/ProtectedOrig/NewData

$ mv NewDataCopy/ /Users/JSG/Desktop/DataFarm/DirectoryName/Data/NewDataCopy

$ chflags -R uchg /Users/JSG/Desktop/DataFarm/DirectoryName/ProtectedOrig/
```

Like I said, I'd like to streamline this. In fact, what I'd really like to do is turn the whole thing into a shell script, and I'm struggling to make it work. Thank you in advance from an eager novice.

Comment: If all you want is to make sure you have original copies, you might investigate configuration management tools, like say git or svn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I'm misunderstanding your question, but you want to merge all that into one script like this?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z "${1}" ]]; then
  die "FolderName Required"
fi

newDirName="DirectoryName"
newBaseDir="~/Desktop/DataFarm/$1/"
/bin/mkdir -p $newBaseDir/{ProtectedOrig,Data}

echo -n "---Data Folder Setup

---Data Introduction

---Data Audit/Manipulation

---Data Queries" > $newBaseDir/Data/DataJournal.txt

ditto NewData/ NewDataCopy
newdata.sh $newDirName
mv NewData/ $newBaseDir/ProtectedOrig/NewData
mv NewDataCopy/ $newBaseDir/Data/NewDataCopy
chflags -R uchg $newBaseDir/ProtectedOrig/
```

Comment: Now that you have it as newdatatest.sh do a `chmod +x newdatatest.sh` to make it executable and then run it: `newdatatest.sh`. I'm using the commands you provided from your post, so some directories may be off (like where is `newdata.sh`?). Where does `NewData` and `NewDataCopy` get created? Should these be ProtectedOrig and Data?

Comment: It was just a minor fix. I made an edit to what to you put together for me and that is that! I'm a newbie so I submitted the edit for peer review. Thank you very, very much.