# How can I move files up one directory and delete old directory without specifically naming files?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I use a shell script that takes a single directory, called `NewData`, with whatever is inside of it, and creates this:

[image]

There is one step I want to add, and I am not sure how to do it. I want to move the contents of `NewData` and `NewDataCopy` into their respective parent directories (`ProtectedOrig` and `Data`) and delete `NewData` and `NewDataCopy`. What command(s) would I add to my script to do this without specifically naming the files to be moved (they will be different every time I run the script)?

If it would help, you can [have a look at the script here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691673/shell-script-to-duplicate-directory-lock-one-and-move-both-to-new-directory-a). I'm grateful for whatever assistance I can get!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can move everything without naming the files specifically by using a "glob" (aka a "wildcard"). That's a `*`.

So let's say you are in `DataDirectory`. You can move everything from `Data/NewDataCopy` up to `Data` by doing this: `mv Data/NewDataCopy/* Data/`. Then delete with a `rmdir Data/NewDataCopy`.

Starting from `DataDirectory` then to do everything you'd do this:

```
mv Data/NewDataCopy/* Data/
rmdir Data/NewDataCopy
mv ProtectedOrig/NewData/* ProtectedOrig/
rmdir ProtectedOrig/NewData
```